# Having trouble saving files to local file system with meteor cordova on android

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I'm trying to save a file, that exists on my server and displays in my app, to download and save to the client's file system. What's the best way to do this in meteor?

My current implementation is using the window.requestFileSystem and FileTransfer (Which I believe is a cordova plugin)

I've also tried LocalFileSystem.PERSISTANT, but then I get an undefined error.

**The code:**

```js
var fileSystem;
//step one is to request a file system  
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0,
  function(fs) {
    fileSystem = fs;
    console.log(fileSystem);

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(imageBaseUrl + origUri);

    fileTransfer.download(
      uri,
      fileSystem.root.fullPath + 'download.pdf',
      function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      },
      false, {
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
      }
    );
  }, function(e) {
    alert('failed to get fs');
    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
  });
```

**The errors I'm getting on Android is as follows:**

*FileSystem object:*

```
name: "temporary"
root: DirectoryEntry
filesystem: FileSystem
fullPath: "/"
isDirectory: true
isFile: false
name: ""
nativeURL: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.app/cache/"
```

*FileTransferError object:*

```
body: null
code: 1
exception: "/download.pdf: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)"
http_status: 200
source: "http://example.com/upload_H5XtiJJRf2Bmeq3d.pdf"
target: "/download.pdf"
```

Thing is, in the AndroidManifest.xml, permission is requested for EXTERNAL_WRITE_ACCESS, so surely the filesystem should be writable then?

Is there some other permission that needs to be granted, and if so, where and how do I request it?

Thanks!